# ubuntu desktop install from usb key

Tags: 14.04, grub2

due to an app that requires a gui I installed ubuntu desktop 14.04 (tried 16 too) on a dell R610 using unetbootin. Everything works fine and I'm able to install. What happens when I go into the desktop though after the reboot is..

1. it runs off the usb key
2. when usbkey is removed after shutdown it then goes into BusyBot

even though the fstab and grub show the correct UUID for the main hard drive it still tries to look for the usb key.

The only way i'm able to get into the desktop is when the busybot screen comes up I type "exit" then it continues to boot in.

Any advice? if you need more information I can look just not sure what else you need.

Thanks

Comment: @karel thanks. It looks like there were a few issues. I will try again without the USB and go through the DRAC to see if that works out the problem. It might be my usb key too so I'll try that thanks.